# How to create a macro in .vimrc which automatically uses enter

Tags: macro

I want to have a macro in my `.vimrc` which when activated will enter a command and execute it.

I want something like

```
let @r = ':e!'
```

but instead of it just being entered in the command line I want it executed.

Answer (score 5):

Your goal is to insert a literal `^M` character. You have two options: You can use digraphs (`:h digraphs`), or the `<C-v>` shortcut (`:h i_CTRL-v`).

### Digraphs

Digraphs are a way to enter hard-to-reach characters, like accented letters or special keys. If you look at the listing in `:digraphs`, you will see that **CR** is the shortcut you want.

To enter a digraph, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> followed by the digraph letters. In this case, it would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (note the uppercase, it's significant).

### Ctrl-v

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> will "insert next non-digit literally". You can either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd> – both will result in `^M`.

Answer (score 3):

Before ending `'` sign, press combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will insert Enter code represented by `^M` sign, which will as you would have pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> yourself.

You should get something like this:

```
let @r = ':e!^M'
```

Comment: if you are using gvim for Windows, you probably need to use c-w rather than c-v

Answer (score 0):

### Q: How to set a macro in vimrc or vimscript?

### A: `let @w = 'macro commands'`

How to find macro commands?

1. Record your macro using `qw <do macro> q`
2. Expand your macro in insert mode using `Ctrl-r Ctrl-r w`

Answer (score -1):

`<cr>` (Carriage Return) inside a mapping or a command will expand to an Enter keystroke.

So your mapping then would be

```
let @r = ':e!<cr>'
```

Comment: I would say that this won't work. It will, if you prefix `<` with a backslash `\ ` and enclose whole expression in double quotes instead of single ones `'` => `"`